# Identifying SMD component 22P W8

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, tv

[image]

[image]

I've been trying to identify a component on a main board for a TV that I believe to be faulty. As I haven't been able to come up with anything that I feel confident about, I'm hoping to get some guidance.

I believe the package to be a SOT23-3.

The markings look like 22P W8.

22P might indicate a JFET and W8 could be a zener diode.

It's located in the path between the +12V coming from the PSU going to 4 pins on the LVDS connector going to the 12VIN on the T-Con board.

There seem to be a crack in the package and the voltage going to the LVDS is unstable and changes when pressure is put on the component. So I don't know what use measurements of the component will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Diodes Inc. DMP2215L, a P-Channel MOSFET from August 2009.

[Datasheet here](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31125.pdf).

From the bottom of the first page you can see how the topcode works.  22P is the chip type, while W8 is the date code.

[image]

Comment: That sounds a lot more plausible than anything I was able to find, thank you. For the benefit of others who might stumble upon this question and my future searches, may I ask how you found it?