# Toshiba T1200XE PSU repair. Identifying some SMD component NA 06

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I am trying to repair a Toshiba T1200XE Power board and naturally all caps are bad and leaking, so the need to be changed.
I have also found a blown component NA 06 that needs to be replaced, but I cannot seem to identify this component or a replacement. Maybe I am not so familiar with SMD components or it is because it is old.
It is the one in the blue circle. I have borrowed this picture [from another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/544370/252145) and added the blue circle.

Can anyone help me so I hope to get it repaired?

[image: Toshiba T1200XE]

Comment: Looks like SOT-223.

Answer (score 0):

`NA` could be one of these: https://smd.yooneed.one/code4e41.html (long list, not copying here.)

If you can identify the exact package (possible SOT-23?), that will help narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try to identify it from there. :-)

Comment: I have being checking on the above with the recommendations from rdtsc and found that it is a SOT-89 and possibly a voltage detection component - S-8051ANB
It seems to be a good match as this is detecting voltages for the battery etc.

Answer (score 0):

2SK1273?  N-channel MOSFET.  Possible answer...

[image]
<sub>Source: https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfview.php?doc=2sk1273.pdf&dire=_nec</sub>

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and explain why you think that? Maybe add a reference or a link?

Comment: @Steve Since you're new here I added the identifying information for you. Next time please do it yourself.